# How to vertically align elements in a table with icons and text?

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, text, center

I have an issue with a table of personal information for a resume, I am not sure how to align and center vertically the text after the icons, so it does not look in the bottom of the cell. Also I reviewed some posts with similar but more complex problems, however I couldn't understand them very well and much less optimize their solution to this simple table.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,onecolumn]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
                \hline
                \includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{Email_Icon} & ONEONEONE &  \includegraphics[height=0.5cm] 
                {SmartPhone_Icon} & ONEONEONE & ~~~\includegraphics[height=0.6cm]{Language_Icon} & 
                 ONEONEONE \\
                \includegraphics[height=0.6cm]{Birthday_Icon} & ONEONEONE &  
                \includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{Nationality_Icon} & ONEONEONE & 
                \includegraphics[height=0.6cm]{Location_Icon} & ONEONEONE \\
                \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: The resultant table, and sketch of what I desire to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

With use of the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[demo, % in real document delete demo option
            export]{adjustbox} % it load graphicx package

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\adjustboxset{height=6mm, width=9mm, % in real document remove width setting
              valign=c, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c X c X c X}
        \hline
   \adjustimage{}{Email_Icon}       & ONEONEONE 
        &  \adjustimage{}{SmartPhone_Icon}      & ONEONEONE 
            &   \adjustimage{}{Language_Icon}   & ONEONEONE \\

    \adjustimage{}{Birthday_Icon}   & ONEONEONE 
        &   \adjustimage{}{Nationality_Icon}    & ONEONEONE 
            &   \adjustimage{}{Location_Icon}   & ONEONEONE \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that exactly does what I was looking for.